# How to find out cgroup of a particular process?

Tags: linux, process, cgroup

Is there any method to get `cgroup` of process?

The only one package that I know (`cgroup-bin`), just provide some manipulations with cgroups and allow to change cgroup of process/list of processes, but no capabilities to know information about cgroup of a particular process.

Comment: Try `ps -o cgroup <pid>`

Comment: cat /proc/<pid>/cgroup

Comment: @MIfe, yes, you are right, ty very much. This is what I need

Comment: @c4f4t0r, your method are not so good, it just output to me all available controllers, but not cgroup of a process, but ty you too.

Comment: @MIfe that's true, sorry, other option is grep on tasks file, for example grep <pid> /cgroup/cpuset/app1/tasks

Comment: @Zerospiel, does the answer below answers your question?

Answer (score 32):

Using systemd (PID 3378 for example):

```
# systemctl status 3378 | grep CGroup
CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope
```

Using proc:

```
# cat /proc/3378/cgroup 
10:memory:/user.slice/user-1000.slice
9:blkio:/user.slice/user-1000.slice
8:net_cls,net_prio:/
7:cpu,cpuacct:/user.slice/user-1000.slice
6:perf_event:/
5:freezer:/
4:cpuset:/
3:pids:/user.slice/user-1000.slice
2:devices:/user.slice/user-1000.slice
1:name=systemd:/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope
```

Looking into /sys/:

```
# cd /sys/fs/ && find * -name "*.procs" -exec grep 3378 {} /dev/null \; 2> /dev/null
cgroup/memory/user.slice/user-1000.slice/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/blkio/user.slice/user-1000.slice/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/net_cls,net_prio/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/cpu,cpuacct/user.slice/user-1000.slice/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/perf_event/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/freezer/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/cpuset/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/pids/user.slice/user-1000.slice/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/devices/user.slice/user-1000.slice/cgroup.procs:3378
cgroup/systemd/user.slice/user-1000.slice/session-3.scope/cgroup.procs:3378
```

Comment: Last command would match as well data about process whose pid is `13378`, or `23378`, or `33378`, etc.

Answer (score 8):

The quickest way to view cgroup of a process is by process name, using this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
THISPID=`ps -eo pid,comm | grep $1 | awk '{print $1}'`
cat /proc/$THISPID/cgroup
```

Comment: use `pgrep`, not `ps | grep | awk`

Answer (score 7):

From RHEL7 and up, and on some other distro's, I find this util helpful:

```
$ systemd-cgtop
```

Before using it, make sure you have `DefaultCPUAccounting=yes` in `/etc/systemd/system.conf`.

I even made some improvements to Egbert's script that is still useful and used Patrick's suggestion to use `pgrep`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "PID  SLICE   SERVICE"
for THISPID in `pgrep $1`; do
  SLICE=$(cat /proc/$THISPID/cgroup | grep '^1:' | awk -F/ '{ print $2 }')
  SERVICE=$(cat /proc/$THISPID/cgroup | grep '^1:' | awk -F/ '{ print $3 }')
  echo "$THISPID $SLICE $SERVICE"
done
```